# How to implement multiple paths of mutable changes in an immutable / functional way?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability

I am messing around with writing a PDF, and it is making apparent a particular problem you sometimes face in programming, and I'm wondering how you would solve it in a functional way.

When generating the PDF, you first generate the pages content, then you write the length of the content first, then the actual content. That's the gist of it. So you have these steps:

1. generate string output, but don't write
2. write length of output
3. write actual string output

In addition, during the first step, we might be modifying some internal records. In PDF rendering, in some cases you create a lazily constructed map of object ids. So as we are generating the initial string output, we are also mutably changing some base records.

How do you separate these concerns? How does a functional programming language solve such a situation?

I start to imaging, well:

1. `map` to generate string
2. but then map to update immutable core object at the same time?

I don't get how it would work. I am trying to find inspiration from functional languages how to simplify this PDF rendering process, or simplify its parts.

It's sort of like the rails `content_for :x` injections. While rendering a template, you specify portlets where you can inject content into from elsewhere. How do you do this sort of thing the functional way?

Comment: Could you explain what are "object" IDs and what exactly do they map to, how is it useful?

Comment: In general, functional programming is about pure functions. Instead of mutating state, you'd return a new version of the state alongside with the result. In the first step you outline above, can you instead return a tuple of the string output *and* the new state?